# What Christianity offers which other religions cannot?

Tags: comparative-christianity, evangelism, comparative-religion

Every religion has its own uniqueness. However, most of the religions have some common grounds to relate to other religions.

Many Christians believe that the Christian faith is not only unique as a religious system but also has some uniqueness in what it offers in terms of faith, experience, and hope, which other religions do not or cannot offer.

My question is to Evangelical Christians. If the above assumption is true what is the evidence?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! This question is really too broad, can you think of any way to narrow it down?

Comment: There is an assumption in your question, which is that religions should chosen based on what they offer rather than whether they are actually true or not.

Comment: Just now edited and updated my above post.

Comment: Since I can't answer... [Sola Gratia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_gratia) is uniquely Christian. Human nature really wants salvation to be about *us*; as a result, man-made religions are about what *we* do to be saved. Christianity teaches that the answer is *nothing*; God already did *everything*. All we have to "do" is accept His Mercy. See Ephesians 2:8-9.

Comment: This is actually a very good question that should have been allowed to be left open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christianity is the only religion, that I know of, that gives a reasonable explanation and a further revelation of the history of the Jewish people.

The recorded history of the Jews in the Old Testament scriptures is the most comprehensive documentation on earth covering a period of four thousand years, written and preserved meticulously by an entire nation, generation by generation.

Many issues were left unresolved by that documentation : the succession of kings, the promise of a Messiah, the resolution of sins, the fact of mankind's sinfulness, the fulfillment of what was set forth in rituals and artifacts and the question of who, exactly, the God of Israel was and how he could be known, personally.

All of this is fully revealed and realised in the coming of Jesus Christ and in the gospel which, in a range of doctrine, explains all that ever came before in Israel.

What is revealed is that the God of Adam, of Abel, of Enoch, of Noah, of Elihu, of Job, of Abraham, of Isaac, of Jacob and of Joseph . . .

. . .  of Moses, of Joshua, of Phinehas, of Caleb . . .

. . . of Gideon and Deborah and Barak and Jephthah and Samson . . .

. . .  of Samuel and all the prophets, of David the king and Hezekiah and Josiah . . .

. . . is the God and Father of the Lord Jesus Christ.

This astounding revelation is not seen, anywhere on earth, in any comparable form, in any  structured and coherent doctrinal explanation, other than in Christianity.

Not only so, but this religion conveys a unique revelation : that of the Church, the Body of Christ (who is the Head of a new humanity).

And more than that, it reveals the end of the world, the judgment of all mankind and the creation of new heavens and a new earth.

All matters from the beginning of time are fully resolved in the coming, the sufferings, the death, the resurrection, the ascension, the current reign and the future return of Jesus Christ of Nazareth, born of the virgin Mary, declared to be the only begotten Son of God and Head over all things to the Church, His body and bride.

Comment: Islam also claims the be the true continuation of the history laid down in the Old Testament, so this isn't really accurate. Also other religious movements like Mormonism (if that isn't considered a denomination of Christianity), the Unification Church, Branch Davidians, etc. claim to continue the history of Christianity and then add their own ideas of either what happened concurrently with the Bible or what has happened since then

Comment: Also the claim that only Christianity "reveals the end of the world, the judgment of all mankind and the creation of new heavens and a new earth" is entirely inaccurate. End time revelations are common to a huge number of religions

Comment: @KevinWells They make claims, yes. But even a brief examination of these _claims_ indicates their unsuitability, their inapplicability and their sheer incompetence.

Comment: And they would say the same about your claims. If we are assuming the validity of the Bible for the sake of answering this question then the unique property of Christianity would be "it's correct", and that would suffice

Comment: @KevinWells Well, sort of.  A Muslim would likely claim that the text of the OT has been meaningfully changed since it was written.  So it would be more accurate to say that "Islam claims to be the true continuation of the history which was once laid down in the Old Testament", which is a different claim altogether.  Whether either claim is meaningful is left to the reader.

Comment: @Spitemaster That doesn't change my point, which is that this answer assumes the validity and accuracy of The Bible, and whether or not that is true, it circumvents the point of the question and makes everything else in the answer irrelevant because as I said, if that is an allowable assumption then the real distinction that Christianity has is its veracity

Comment: @KevinWells It does because the point at issue is not whether the Bible is accurate but rather whether it has been corrupted.  Christianity is based on the Jewish scriptures as they exist today.  Islam is not (depends who you ask, but that's still significantly different from Christianity).  However, I agree that this answer is mostly incidental and not a particularly good distinction.

Comment: @Spitemaster ok, then disregard the part about Islam, and instead look at the other religious groups I mentioned, they accept the Bible as authoritative, but add to it with their own doctrines. They accept the claims that Nigel said are unique to Christianity, but are not themselves Christians (even if they claim to be). Therefore this answer is simply wrong

Comment: @KevinWells Okay, fair enough.

Comment: @KevinWells You seem to be discriminating against certain people who identify as 'Christian'. The website does not discriminate in the way in which you are attempting to do so.

Comment: @NigelJ That is not my intent, my intent is to say that there are multiple religions with the traits you put forward, including those who would not self identify as christian, so they are not traits that are unique to christianity. To be clear, some self identify as christian, so for the sake of this site it can assumed that they are, but some definitely do not

Comment: NigelJ is on point here.  "And you shall know the truth, and the truth shall set you free"  The question might as well ask "What does the truth offer that the lies do not?" for the very fact that the Gospel of God is the truth IS it's distinction.

Answer (score 10):

C.S. Lewis answered this question:

> During a British conference on comparative religions, experts from around the world debated what, if any, belief was unique to the Christian faith. They began eliminating possibilities. Incarnation? Other religions had different versions of gods' appearing in human form. Resurrection? Again, other religions had accounts of return from death. The debate went on for some time until C. S. Lewis wandered into the room. "What's the rumpus about?" he asked, and heard in reply that his colleagues were discussing Christianity's unique contribution among world religions. Lewis responded, "Oh, that's easy. It's grace."[1](http://www.graceguy.org/blog-posts/whats-so-unique-about-christianity-cs-lewis-answers)

I agree - if I had to summarise it in one word, it would be "Grace". Most other religions require people to try really, really hard to be worthy enough. Only in Christianity does God himself come to us to make us worthy, not as a reward for our hard work but as a free gift of grace.

I think that is the fundamental thing which distinguishes Christianity from other religions.

Comment: Great answer!  My  previous Pastor used to say that all the other religions say "Do, do, do" and Christianity is the only one that says "Done."

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible to speak for every other religion without knowing what every other religion teaches. However, I can give a brief summary of what I believe is unique about Christianity.

> “for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God,” Romans‬ ‭3:23‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

> “For the wages of sin is death, but the gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.” Romans‬ ‭6:23‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

> “For God so loved the world that He gave His only begotten Son, that whoever believes in Him should not perish but have everlasting life.” John‬ ‭3:16‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

> “But God demonstrates His own love toward us, in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us.” Romans‬ ‭5:8‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

> “not by works of righteousness which we have done, but according to His mercy He saved us, through the washing of regeneration and renewing of the Holy Spirit,” Titus‬ ‭3:5‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

> “But God, who is rich in mercy, because of His great love with which He loved us, even when we were dead in trespasses, made us alive together with Christ (by grace you have been saved), and raised us up together, and made us sit together in the heavenly places in Christ Jesus, that in the ages to come He might show the exceeding riches of His grace in His kindness toward us in Christ Jesus. For by grace you have been saved through faith, and that not of yourselves; it is the gift of God, not of works, lest anyone should boast.” Ephesians‬ ‭2:4-9‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

Christianity teaches that all of us have sinned and are deservedly condemned to death. But in spite of our unworthiness, God loves us and sent Jesus Christ to save us. Christ died for us while we were still sinners, while undeserving of His mercy. The salvation He offers is based on His goodness and faithfulness, not by any righteousness or good works on our part. It is a gift we receive, not a reward that we earn.

In short, Christianity is a religion that is based on God who sacrifices Himself for our salvation, rather than us sacrificing ourselves to convince Him to save us. That may be unique to Christianity.

However, there is a sense in which we sacrifice ourselves.

> “I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that you present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable to God, which is your reasonable service.” Romans‬ ‭12:1‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

> “For we are His workmanship, created in Christ Jesus for good works, which God prepared beforehand that we should walk in them.” Ephesians‬ ‭2:10‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

But our sacrifice and our good works are not for the purpose of earning salvation; they are our response to God’s free gift of grace.

Comment: _I urge you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that you present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable to God, which is your reasonable service._ [Romans 12:1, KJV]

Comment: True, but our sacrifice is not as a means of salvation but a response to it. Perhaps I should have been clearer about that.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit to make that clear.

Comment: How does it look now?

Comment: That is clearer. I must confess I was hasty in downvoting this answer. I should have given time to edit. I can't change the vote now, but I up-voted your other answer, which I had not noticed previously. Kind regards.

Comment: No worries. I’m new here so I was reading the instructions. I think I read that clicking down again removes a down vote and clicking up changes it to an up vote. But I’ve never tried it myself because I don’t think i can vote yet. In any case, I hope my future contributions prove useful.

Comment: Nigel J may be unable to change his vote but perhaps I can rectify that situation for you.  Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.

Comment: Mormonism and other non-mainstream offshoots of Christianity still believe in those passages and doctrines, and therefore provide the same feature, so the validity of this answer depends on whether or not those sects are or are not Christian

Comment: Given the broadness of the question, it seemed appropriate to paint with a broad brush. There may be non-mainstream Christian denominations that adhere to this concept and there are members of mainstream denominations that do not. I believe such detailed answers will have to wait for a detailed question.

Comment: @KevinWells As previously, some may _claim_ to adhere to certain texts and truths but when their claims are examined, their claims may be found to be false. This website is not able to discriminate between self-identifying 'Christians'. You appear to be doing so.